# Read performance counters periodically in linux

Tags: linux, perf

Is there a way to read performance counters periodically in linux?

Something like `perf stat` with the ability to sample every X cycles is what I'm looking for.

Basically I would like to be able to read the instruction counter (number of instructions executed) every X amount of cpu cycles for some program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the perf tool in Linux works by recording an event when the counters reach a specific value, rather than sampling at regular intervals.

Command `perf record -e cycles,instructions -c 10000` stores an event every 10000 cycles and every 10000 instructions. It can be run against a new command or an existing pid. It records to `perf.data` in current directory.

Analyzing the data is another matter. Using `perf script` gets you quite close:

```
ls 16040 2152149.005813: cycles:          c113a068  ([kernel.kallsyms])
ls 16040 2152149.005820: cycles:          c1576af0  ([kernel.kallsyms])
ls 16040 2152149.005827: cycles:          c10ed6aa  ([kernel.kallsyms])
ls 16040 2152149.005831: instructions:          c1104b30  ([kernel.kallsyms])
ls 16040 2152149.005835: cycles:          c11777c1  ([kernel.kallsyms])
ls 16040 2152149.005842: cycles:          c10702a8  ([kernel.kallsyms])
...
```

You need to write a script that takes a bunch of lines from that output and counts the number of 'cycles' and 'instructions' events in that set. You can adjust the resolution by changing the parameter `-c 10000` in the recording command.

I verified the analysis by running `perf stat` and `perf record` against `ls /`. Stat reported 2 634 205 cycles, 1 725 255 instructions, while script output had 410 cycles events and 189 instructions events. The smaller the `-c` value, the more overhead there seems to be in the cycles reading.

There is also a `-F` option to `perf record`, which samples at regular intervals. However, I could not find a way to retrieve the counter values when using this option.

**Edit:** `perf stat` apparently works on pids also, and captures data until ctrl-c is pressed. It should be quite easy to modify the source so that it always captures for N seconds and then run it in a loop.

Comment: How do you run perf script?
I tried running
`perf record -e cycles,instructions -c 10000 -R ls;`
`perf script`, but I get a **Fatal: no event_list!** error.

Comment: @Skim strange, for me just typing `perf script` works. Does `perf report` work for you, i.e. is the recorded perf.data file ok?

Comment: Turns out I was using an older version of perf (2.6).
perf 3.0.38 works as you stated above.
I'll come back and upvote you when I have enough rep.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Good news: In the next kernel (Linux 3.9), perf stat will have an option `-I msecs` to print event deltas at regular time intervals.

https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/2004891/

> ```
> $ perf stat -I 1000 -e cycles noploop 10
> noploop for 10 seconds
> 1.000086918         2385155642 cycles                    #    0.000 GHz
> 2.000267937         2392279774 cycles                    #    0.000 GHz
> 3.000385400         2390971450 cycles                    #    0.000 GHz
> 4.000504408         2390996752 cycles                    #    0.000 GHz
> 5.000626878         2390853097 cycles                    #    0.000 GHz
> ```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-stat.1.html

> ```
> -I msecs, --interval-print msecs
> ```
>
> Print count deltas every N milliseconds (minimum: 10ms)

Comment: The option is `-I 1000` for 1 sec printing: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-stat.1.html - `-I msecs, --interval-print msecs` "Print count deltas every N milliseconds (minimum: 10ms)"

Answer (score 0):

You can easily modify perf stat to do this.

In fact, I have a crude modification already implemented and would be glad to share this change with you..

The changes I made are mostly in the run_perf_stat function within the while(!done) loop

Just move the lines below the while(!done) {sleep(1);} to inside the loop and change the sleep to a nanosleep with the time period that you wish to sample at

That should make perf print the output on STDOUT(or STDERR)

If you wish to store these values, I suggest you create a 2-Dimensional array of type struct stats, update this with every sample and write periodically to a file