# Read performance counters every N instructions in Linux

Tags: linux, kernel, perf

I'm trying to gather the number of cycles every N instructions(N is fixed), using `perf record` or `perf stat` command on Linux.
However, when I tried using `perf record -e cycles,instructions -c N`, I only got the information on two separate events, which is not what I want.
Another attempt was made using `perf record -I N ...`. However, it seems like the `-I` argument can only sample on the period of time, not the number of instructions.
The thread here [Read performance counters periodically in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132096/read-performance-counters-periodically-in-linux) suggested that we could write a script to do so. However, I couldn't get the point how to manipulate the interspersed data collected by two separate events.