# How to find which part of a program takes the most time (including kernel time and context-switching)

Tags: linux, performance, profiling, perf

When doing performance analysis on CPU-intensive work, I generally use `sudo perf record -a -s -e cpu-clock -g <executable>`. But that doesn't show how much time is spent on context-switch, how much time is spent in network stack, which I think is not super helpful to a network-IO-bounded task.

My specific case:
I have a program which load data from gcs, deserialize it.

I have verified the peak throughput could be >200MBps, but initialization time takes 4.5 seconds, of which 1 second is spent on authentication, the other 3.5 seconds is really loading the data.

The data initialization reads metadata for ~300 files, but each file only read 1.25MB.

This is the abstract context for my specific case. I want to know if there's any tools available in linux(ubuntu), to see which part of my program takes the most of the time? So that I could make some changes to it.

Comment: Any chance the units for your 200MBps baseline got mixed up between megabytes and megabits? I ask because 300 * 1.25MB in 3.5 seconds would be ~1Gbit. Maybe you're on 10Gb ethernet, but otherwise that might be your cap.

Comment: @Ari No, the peak is 200MBps. This only proves the bandwidth is super enough.

Comment: Perf can do much more than just counting cpu-cycles for the whole program. Please read https://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132096/read-performance-counters-periodically-in-linux . There are counters for context switches, and also processor-specific ones. Note that for advanced high-level profiling, VTune may be more helpful. Note that if you have a HDD or a network device, the timing seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Why record `-a`?  That's system-wide, not for this process.  Normal per-process timing *does* count time spent in the kernel running system calls.  With the right options (stack sampling) you can attribute each sample to parent functions to find which callers are to blame for invoking time consuming stuff (e.g. because of many separate calls to some small functions, even if those functions have many other callers.)

Comment: @JérômeRichard will take a look, thanks for the pointer!